# GCP : Restrict actions on GKE resources using custom organization policies - bin authz

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

i created this custom org policy:

[image]

When I enforce this policy to my project, I am getting error: project instance not found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right project, you can run this command on your vm to see if you are in the right project: gcloud config list (Can see project details and account details).

Take a look at this post in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/0SkO60y8TR8/m/6n5n9p5VN3EJ) and also Follow this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/custom-org-policies) will help you in resolving this concern.